# Delay laravel push notification for 5 second

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using ""davibennun/laravel-push-notification": "dev-laravel5" " for sending push notification. What i want is delay in sending notification after hit but dont want to stop the process. Is there any idea how can i do this or is this possible?

Following is the code to send push notification:

```
     $pushNotification = PushNotification::app('appNameAndroid')->to($token);
     $pushNotification->adapter->setAdapterParameters(['sslverifypeer' => false]);
     $pushNotification->send($message);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless the library itself offers a means of doing that, I'm afraid you're stuck with [`sleep`](http://php.net/sleep). Of course you could do something overly complicated like creating a queue with X amount of seconds in the future, but honestly that seems like major overkill. Actually I take that back, a queue may be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @Andrew I will try to use queue. Thanks for advise.

Comment: @Andrew Do you have any example how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I found how to do this.
Following are the steps.

1. Run the following command

   php artisan queue:table
       php artisan migrate
2. Change .env

   QUEUE_DRIVER=database
3. Create a job

   php artisan make:job JobName

//In Job file

4. I have mentioned 2 protected variable in my job file

   $message,$deviceToken
5. In _construct i assigned a value to the above variables.

   public function __construct($deviceToken, $message)

   ```
   {
       $this->deviceToken = $deviceToken;
       $this->message = $message;
   }
   ```
6. In handle method

   $pushNotification = PushNotification::app('appNameAndroid')->to($this->deviceToken);
               $pushNotification->adapter->setAdapterParameters(['sslverifypeer' => false]);
               $pushNotification->send($this->message);

//In my controller

```
$job = (new JobName($deviceToken, $message))->delay(10);

$this->dispatch($job);
```